# Why is Django not filling out variable entries?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my settings.py I define a nonempty SITE_NAME:

```
 SITE_NAME = 'Pets Gallery'
```

In my views.py I have:

```
def all_pets(request):
    pets = models.Pet.objects.all()
    random.shuffle(pets)
    return render(request, 'multiple_pets.html', {
      'pets': pets,
      'site_name': settings.SITE_NAME,
      'page_name': 'All the pets we have!'})
```

In the present version of the templates, the base template has:

```
<title>{{  page_name }} - {{ site_name }}</title>
...
<h1>{{ page_name }}</h1>
```

The specific template is just a stub that extends the base class; I want to customize it but I'm working on smoke testing for now.

The rendered page appears to be treating all values as empty. The rendered HTML source has:

```
<title> - </title>
...
<h1></h1>
```

Why would it be treating variables (for the moment, nonempty strings) as empty, unavailable, etc.?

**--UPDATE--**

A commenter asked my `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py`. I realized that I did not have directories included; I changed that to include:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pets/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pets.wsgi.application'
```

That solved the immediate problem of my not getting a login screen. Now I can get to a login screen. However, this unearthed additional problems, which I think would better be entered on a separate question.

Comment: Neither `'pets'` gets printed ?

Comment: "pets" is empty now; I definitely want to change it, but it is meant to be built out of entries in a model / table that is presently empty. I was trying to set an immediate goal of string inclusion before tackling the more advanced stuff.

Comment: What about your `TEMPLATES` list setting inside your `settings.py` file? Could you share it please?

Comment: Glad I could help!